# Work around on NodeJS blocking main thread

Tags: node.js, express, server

We just had our NodeJS server hanging with 100% CPU, after debugging it turns out to be caused by a bad regex Catastrophic Backtracking.

I know that by design NodeJS is single threaded, so if some bad code blocks the thread then the whole server hangs. Is there no clever way to work around this, so let's say if it hangs more than 1 minute, we can detect and autorestart the server.